# Problem booting 20.04

Tags: boot, acpi, 20.04

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 form a pen drive (dual boot with Windows 10) and everything went fine. After restarting I got the file system checking (Pic. 1) and then an error screen (Pic. 2):

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug)....
ACPI Error: skipping while/if block...
Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding  failed
```

This behavior first appeared suddenly in my previous 18.04 installation and I couldn't solve it. Now I thought that a fresh install could solve the problem but it persists.

My device is an ASUS R73U.

Please help!

Thanks in advance

File system check :

[image]

Errors :

[image]

Comment: There is a bugreport at [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/1870260](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/1870260) - this seems to describe your problem, and suggest a potential solution.

Comment: I tried the suggested solution in the bug report but didn't work. Also, the ACPI errors seem to be a still unsolved kernel problem since 2018 (kinda disappointing). I am still digging into the errors and possible solutions. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Does the command `journalctl -b -p3` produce any results that indicate something fatal?